# no sound in system and alsamixer says :"The sound device does not have any control"

Tags: sound, alsa

I m facing sound problem. There is no sound in my system.When I looked for alsamixer, there it says :"The sound device does not have any control". But if I connect it to external speaker its works fine.
What does it mean?

Comment: Since nobody more knowledgeable is commenting: I assume you are running alsamixer from a terminal and seeing the character graphics display it presents. If not, do so and see what happens - especially any messages which appear on the terminal and post the results here. the only other thing I can think of is that you may have turned alsa off somehow. Although it's the most common sound infrastructure, it's not the only one. Please edit your question adding your distro, version, sound card make and model, computer make and model, so people have some idea of your actual situation.